# Passing a block as an argument

Tags: ruby, parameters, arguments, block, proc

just playing with some random string generation and getting my knickers in a twist over how to pass an argument to a method which gets re-evaluated each time. Here's where i'm at with the code:

```
random_letter = ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)]

random_string = "".ljust(141, random_letter)
```

Of course the issue here is that random_letter only gets created once, then that same instance is used 141 times, I'm trying to get random_letter to be generated on each of the 141 occasions that "" is padded with random_letter.

I'm sure there are likely easier ways of ultimately achieving a 141 random char string and i'd be interested to see better suggestion too, howveer i would like to work out how to achieve this using that path that i chose above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do that using `ljust`. All arguments are evaluated prior to execution of the main method. Whatever code you insert in the second argument position of `ljust`, that will be evaluated into a certain object, and that single object will be used in `ljust`.

One way to do what you want is:

```
26.times.with_object(""){|_, s| s << [*"a".."z"][rand(26)]}
#=> "zjqmdumyrmmfnwsdjysvtolxjn"
```

Comment: A variant: `26.times.map { [*"a".."z"][rand(26)] }.join`. Haven't seen you for awhile. On a beach somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As sawa has already pointed out that it can't be done the way you're trying to do it, however there are other ways to do it with a slight modification in your code:

```
random_letter = proc { [*'a'..'z'].sample }
random_string = 141.times.with_object(''){ |_, s| s << ''.ljust(1, random_letter.call) }
p random_string
# => "cnvmixiolqsgtdbdjrjsmaulslyphvcmvxnheulnrsxdqqryqgrplenyyneagufglkxqsyowbcfdgejwafrubqfnkvnehdtkhygmtpizbgzkyboyqhlrxqdzhglnsigtaglviaesphois"
```

or

```
random_string = 141.times.with_object(''){ |_, s| s << ''.ljust(1, [*'a'..'z'].sample) }
p random_string
# => "wcgkqliwyggfyvxfblyalqgpdbrqvlikxuqwyecihvdkytsbsikhwldvsjamkiicytfcgvvmoeuleeftzizrscujejkuanrxbqwzcywtboidrftinayfvqdygqwrfjhxvyiazzxinjudm"
```